# how to insert node in existing xml file inside search specific existing node then insert child custom node using php

Tags: php, xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="profile">
        <fieldset name="profile" label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_SLIDER_LABEL">
            <field name="address1" type="text" id="address1" description="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS1_DESC" filter="string" label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS1_LABEL" size="30"/>
        </fieldset>
    <fields>
</from>
```

How to insert node using php inside the fields existing node.

I will use bellow code for insert but not insert node properly.

```
 $xmlfile = "profiles/profile.xml"; 
                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                $dom->load($xmlfile);

                $findnode= $dom->getElementsByTagName("/fieldset")->item(0);
                $dom->documentElement->insertBefore($dom->createElement('section',"asdsad"),$findnode);
$dom->save($xmlfile);
```

> > It run but will insert node inside the form node not insert inside the **fieldset** node.

Comment: Use php DOMDocument http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i will find solution at below code.....

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->load($xmlfile);   
        $ids = $dom->getElementsByTagName('fieldset')->item(0);

        $child = $dom->createElement('tagname');
        $child->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('some text'));
        $ids->appendChild($child);
```